# Sunspot: how to do a fulltext query on multiple fields with different values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, full-text-search, sunspot

I'd like to reproduce the following raw solr query with sunspot

```
q=exact_term_text:foo OR term_textv:foo* OR alternate_text:bar*
```

but I am not able to understand if and how this is possible, through the standard sunspot interface, since it seems that:

1. the `fulltext` method does not seem to accept multiple text/search_fields arguments
2. I wouldn't know what argument to pass as the first one to `fulltext`, as if I pass either `"foo"` or `"bar"` the results would not match
3. If I pass an empty argument I get a `q=*:*`
4. the scope filters (e.g. `with(:term).starting_with('foo*')` are (as the name implies) applied as filter queries, and thus take no part in scoring.

It seems possible to hand-compose the string (or possibly use `adjust_solr_params`) but that seems hackish. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Sunspot 2.0.0, there is undocumented and unsupported behaviour that does work. The author himself suggests it shouldn't and it probably won't in future versions.

You can pass multiple fulltext calls into the search definition

```
Post.search do
    fulltext "foo", {:fields => :exact_term}
    fulltext "bar", {:fields => :alternate}
end
```

This results in a solr query of (from the logs)

```
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select 
params={fl=*+score&start=0&q=_query_:"{!dismax+qf%3D'exact_term'}foo"+_query_:"{!dismax+qf%3D'alternate'}bar"&wt=ruby&fq=type:Post&rows=30}
hits=1 status=0 QTime=7
```

Matching substrings is covered in
https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Matching-substrings-in-fulltext-search

Changing the default operator (AND/OR) can be done by adding a option
    minimum_match 1
as mentioned in http://blog.tonycode.com/archives/192

Comment: using (edge)ngrams is not the exactly same thing cause it wouldn't let me differentiate programmatically between queries where a partial match is ok and not without indexing the same field twice. It does seem that susnpot's use of the dismax query handler won't let me do lucene queries without hackish solutions so I'm accepting the answer anyway, thanks.

Comment: In the Sunspot documentation at https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Fulltext-search it explicitly states: "Note that the `keywords` method should not be called multiple times in one search - successive calls will overwrite the previously specified keywords." *(`keywords` is aliased to `fulltext`, they're the same method.)* So according to the authors, your solution won't work... yet it appears to work perfectly. Hmmm, someone is lying.

Comment: Maybe fulltext should not be called on the same field twice.

Comment: I double checked with @nick-zadrozny, as I thought the documentation might be wrong. He confirmed the documentation is correct, you can't call it twice. https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/472

Comment: Please down vote this, it is incorrect. I wasted a day before reading the fine print here.

Comment: Post updated to reflect versions used where this did work. Sorry @pferrel that you wasted a whole day; software changes.

Comment: OK, I understand. I need this feature, separate queries on separate fields. The mailing list seems inactive, how to you contact the maintainer?

Comment: Added my specific question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124787/sunspot-two-fulltext-queries-on-two-fields

Answer (score 2):

If the [documentation](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Fulltext-search) is correct, you can't call `fulltext` twice. So I ended up running two searches and calculating the intersection of both search.

```
a = Post.search do
    fulltext "foo", {:fields => :exact_term}
end

b = Post.search do
    fulltext "bar", {:fields => : alternate}
end

result = a & b
```

How you compute the intersection will depend on what exactly you are trying to accomplish. The above intersection is a little naive. For example, you may want to normalize the score of each result against the max, and use the average of the normalized score for sorting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I also need to have multiple fulltext search for different fields, with different values. Moreover I need to have all conditions to be fulfilled. In other words I need that both 'foo' and 'bar' should be in Post for exact_term and alternate fields.

```
Post.search do
    fulltext "foo", {:fields => :exact_term}
    fulltext "bar", {:fields => :alternate}
end
```

The problem was that I couldn't change my schema.xml settings (defaultOperator). It was set to 'OR'. If you have similar problem you can workaround it like that:

```
Post.search do
    adjust_solr_params do |params|
        params[:q] = params[:q].gsub(/\s_query/, " AND _query") if params[:q].present?
    end
end
```