# Sunspot two fulltext queries on two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I need to do something like the following, which is meant to issue two different queries on two fields.

```
Video.search do
   fulltext weighting_factors, {:fields => :categories_as_string}
   fulltext prefs, {:fields => :similar_as_string}
end
```

Currently I force the two fields to include tokens that have separate namespaces and combine the query to apply to both fields. I think this is equivalent since prefs will never match something in categories_as_string but it's a pain to maintain. Is there a way to do the query above instead?

```
query = prefs + weighting_factors
search = Video.search do
  fulltext query do
    fields :similar_as_string, :categories_as_string
  end
end
```